# Address of an overloaded C++ template function involving SFINAE

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I need to get the address of an overloaded template function that involves SFINAE.  A good example of this scenario would be boost::asio::spawn found here...

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/spawn.html

How would I find the address of this particular instance...

```
template<
    typename Function,
    typename Executor>
void spawn(
    const Executor & ex,
    Function && function,
    const boost::coroutines::attributes & attributes = boost::coroutines::attributes(),
    typename enable_if< is_executor< Executor >::value >::type* = 0);
```

I've unsuccessfully tried this...

```
using Exec = boost::asio::io_context;
using Func = std::function<void(boost::asio::yield_context)>;
void (*addr)(Exec, Func) = boost::asio::spawn;
```

Comment: Use static_cast.

Comment: That function takes **four** arguments. You can't assign its address to a pointer-to-function-taking-two-arguments, because that's not what it is. This has nothing to do with templates. Try it with an ordinary function with default arguments.

Answer (score 4):

`boost::asio::spawn` is not a function.  It is a function *template*.  It's a blueprint from which functions can be created.  There's no way to get a pointer to a function template because it's a purely compile-time construct.

`boost::asio::spawn<Func, Exec>` is a function overload set, but it has no overload that matches the signature `void(Exec,Func)`.  Remember, default function arguments are just syntactic sugar.  Those arguments are still part of the function's signature.

Those two issues make getting a pointer to `boost::asio::spawn` hard and ugly.  It would be much easier to use a lambda.  A lambda will let you preserve type deduction and take advantage of the default arguments:

```
auto func = [](auto&& exec, auto&& func) {
    boost::asio::spawn(std::froward<decltype(exec)>(exec),
                       std::forward<decltype(func)>(func));
};
```

Even if you absolutely need a function pointer, a lambda is still probably the way to go.  You lose parameter type deduction, but can still take advantage of the function's default arguments:

```
void(*addr)(const Exec&, Func) = [](const Exec& exec, Func func) {
    boost::asio::spawn(exec, std::move(func));
};
```

This works because captureless lambdas can be converted to raw function pointers.

If you really, absolutely need a pointer directly to one of the `spawn` instantiations for some reason, you can get it, but it's not pretty:

```
using Exec = boost::asio::io_context::executor_type;
using Func = std::function<void(boost::asio::yield_context)>;

void(*addr)(const Exec&, Func&, const boost::coroutines::attributes&, void*) = boost::asio::spawn<Func&, Exec>;
```

You lose a lot in doing so though.  Not only do you lose argument type deduction and the default arguments, you also lose the ability to pass both lvalues and rvalues to the function since you no longer have a deduced context for forwarding references to work in.  I've to get a pointer to the instantiation accepting an lvalue-reference to the function.  If you want it to accept rvalue-references instead, use

```
void(*addr)(const Exec&, Func&&, const boost::coroutines::attributes&, void*) = boost::asio::spawn<Func, Exec>;
```

Also note that this function takes four parameters.  Call it with, i.e.

```
addr(my_io_context.get_executor(), my_function, boost::coroutines::attributes{}, nullptr);
```

[Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a95f12b86d2c8af)

Comment: What would the "hard and ugly" way be?  There's a reason for needing the actual function address that I won't go into here

Comment: @user1715664 Added.  I told you it's not pretty.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to put this solution as an edit in the question where it'd be visible right off, but the moderators seem to think it's better to force a reader through to here...

```
using Exec = boost::asio::io_context;
using Func = std::function<void(boost::asio::yield_context)>;
using Attr = boost::coroutines::attributes;

void (*addr)(const Exec&,
             Func&&,
             const Attr&,
             typename enable_if< is_executor< Executor >::value>::type*
            ) = boost::asio::spawn<Func, Exec>;
```

Yes, ugly but not too too bad.

Comment: BTW, I removed your answer from the question, and I'm not a moderator. Just a regular member of the community. We like to keep things tidy here, and answers belong in answers, not inside the question itself. If you want to read more about it, I suggest [this meta question and its answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que)